# how to open and query your own sqlite file and display it in ListView with StickyListHeadersAdapter android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Hi i have my own sqlite file and put in inside the assets folder it has multiple table inside. I  want to query different table and display it in a listview. I've search different tutorial but it makes me confuse how will i call the different table? do i need to create a data model for each table and do i need to declare each table in my databasehelper? i always see's tutorial that you will create a database instead of using your own database. thank you

Answer (score 0):

To use an existing database file(pre-populated with data), you can try [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) on github.

To prepare the database files, I recommand [sqliteman](http://sqliteman.yarpen.cz/)

1. Create a database file in sqliteman, say "mydatabase", import the data. you can create multiple tables in a database file.
2. Put this file in assets/databases/ folder in your Android project.
3. Use this file with SQLiteAssetHelper

> how will i call the different table?

You specify the table name in your SQL query, here is a very simple code, just for your references.

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase"; // This is the database file under assets/databases/ folder

    private SQLiteDatabase readableDB;
    private SQLiteDatabase writeableDB;

    private static MyDatabase instance;
    public static synchronized MyDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MyDatabase(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        readableDB = getReadableDatabase();
        writeableDB = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // Suppose tableA has two columns, name and id.
    public ArrayList<String> selectNameById(String Id) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query = "SELECT name FROM tableA WHERE id=?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { Id };
        Cursor cursor = readableDB.rawQuery(query, whereArgs);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Integer nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
                String name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                result.add(name);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```